# Is there cleaner regex for .so libs names?

Tags: c, regex, posix

I am using `<regex.h>` and trying to write a regex for `.so` names including names such as `libmath.so.01`.

Is there a cleaner regex I can use ? what I came out with is:

```
"^lib[[:alnum:],[:punct:]]*[.]so[[:alnum:],[:punct:],.]*$"
```

Comment: `so` must be followed by a dot or nothing

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte doesn't my regex filter strings only contains `.so` in it ?

Comment: it contains too `lib.sos.115`, `lib.so.`, `lib.evil.sorcery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear which part of the filename you want to capture so i made multiple version:

`(^lib.*?\.so(?:$|.\d+))`

Matches strings starting with lib and ends with .so or .so. followed by a digit. And captures the filename.

`\blib\w*?\.so(?:$|.\d+)\b`

Matches strings with in it somewhere libSomthing1.so or libSomthing1.so.01. And doesn't capture anything.